# Phonegap (Cordova), Android, Admob: AdView overlaps WebView

Tags: android, cordova, admob, adview

I'm developing an application for Android, using Phonegap ( also known as Apache Cordova nowadays) and I plan on having ads from Google Admob. I have the following piece of code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
    adView.setMinimumHeight(75);
    adView.setMinimumWidth(320);
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView);
    layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);              //This centers the ads in landscape mode.
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

}

This successfully displays an ad on the bottom of my page but the AdView covers part of my WebView... I tried solving the problem but my skills on the java part of phonegap are very limited :-/

Comment: as a workaround I added bottom: 75px to body in my css but it's not really a good solution